# Type error in Type-Script with Vue.js and Databinding

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

i am pretty fresh in the world of java/type script....

I want to perform a simple task, which currently costs me more than three days in development. I am even not sure why this does happen, since compiling and building are running without an error.

I am using vue.js3:

The Template with error:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import type {CompanyPojo} from "@/rest/restapi-companies";
import {createNewCompany} from "@/rest/restapi-companies";

let companyPojo: CompanyPojo;

</script>


<template>

  <input id="cName" v-model="companyPojo.name" placeholder="Company Name"/>
  <label for="cName">Company Name</label>

<!--  <input id="cAddName" v-model="companyPojo.additionalName" placeholder="Company Additional Name"/>-->
<!--  <label for="cAddName">Company Additional Name</label>-->


<!--  <input id="cLegalForm" v-model="companyPojo.legalForm" placeholder="Company Legal Form"/>-->
<!--  <label for="cLegalForm">Company Legal Form</label>-->

  <button @click="createNewCompany(Object.assign(companyPojo))"> Add Company
  </button>


</template>
```

and this is my TypeScript-File:

```
export type CompanyPojo = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    legalForm: string;
    additionalName: string;
};

export type CompanyPojoResponse = {
    data: CompanyPojo[];
};

export async function createNewCompany(newCompany: CompanyPojo) {

    try {
        const {data, status} = await axios.post<CompanyPojoResponse>('http://localhost:9050/api/v1/company/create-new', newCompany,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    Authorization: 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                },
            },
        );

        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

        // ?? "response status is: 200"
        console.log('response status is: ', status);

        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
            console.log('error message: ', error.message);
            console.log('error message: ', error);
            return error.message;
        } else {
            console.log('unexpected error: ', error);
            return 'An unexpected error occurred';
        }
    }


}
```

As i imported the exported files, i expected that all those types would be availble (which there are in dev and start time).

But then, simply when opening the New-Company View, the view is empty and i see in the console this error:

TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is undefined
setup http://localhost:9050/assets/CompanyNewView-215ff09f.js:1

Removing:

```
 <input id="cName" v-model="companyPojo.name" placeholder="Company Name"/>
  <label for="cName">Company Name</label>
```

Solves to problem.

This driving me nuts, how in the world i can bind and use those value?
I even don't know why this is not working at all.....

Comment: The error seems to came from `companyPojo`. Try to initialize an empty object, this will fix your problem

Comment: i think i am lost, in java the synax would be simply new CompanyPojo(), but idk how this works in JS/TS/Vue exactly ( i am researching it now by myself... )

would be: let companyPojo = {
  name: '',
  additionalName: '',
  legalForm: '',
};

i am trying this one....

Comment: `let companyPojo: CompanyPojo = { id:0, name: '',legalForm: '',additionalName: ''}`

Comment: yep, just without the id, because the backend handles it. seem working :) thanks!

but still, i am curious about the 2nd answer.... (that one with ref)

Comment: For me the error came because you access companyPojo.name but name is actually not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data should be reactive in order to be bound correctly try to use `ref` to create your data property :

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import {ref} from 'vue'
import type {CompanyPojo} from "@/rest/restapi-companies";
import {createNewCompany} from "@/rest/restapi-companies";

const companyPojo = ref<CompanyPojo>({});

</script>
```

Comment: thanks. i  immediatly tried it, but now i get this error:

TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3, '(value: CompanyPojo): Ref<{ id: number; name: string; legalForm: string; additionalName: string; }>', gave the ... (ect)

Comment: That's because the type `{}` is not compatible with your `CompanyPojo` type. You need to fill in all the attributes you set in your type with a value. In Java, it would be like calling a constructor with no arguments, when the only one defined is a constructor with 3 arguments, you can't do that.